# Is there any method to get the SMTP of an email?

Tags: email, smtp, swiftmailer

Usually it works to use "smtp.domain.com" or "mail.domain.com".
Other times, it works to get the MX record of a domain name and try it.

But I have found several times when these methods does not get the real SMTP server.

Is there any way to get, for sure, the SMTP server?

If not, is there any other methods than the 2 described above ?